# Datagrid scrollbar not showing when programmatically changing attribute

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, mxml

I am developing a Flex app that allows a user to click a toggle button. The Datagrid will display the info.  When setting attribute *enabled* in ToggleButtonBar to `true` or `false`, programmatically, at run time, the Datagrid scrollbar does not show when the length of the data exceeds the screen height.  However, if I hard code `enabled = "true"`, it works fine.  Does anyone know how to make the scroll bar work?

Here is the code snippet:

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar id="choices" dataProvider="{viewstack}" 
enabled="{module != Utils.MODULE_NOT_SELECTED}" horizontalGap="5" verticalGap="5"/>

<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack" width="100%" height="100%" creationPolicy="all"
    selectedIndex="0">

<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" label="VM Info">
<mx:DataGrid id="vminfoTbl" width="100%" height="100%" 
 dataProvider="{vnics}" variableRowHeight="true">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="vm" headerText="Name" 
 itemRenderer="{new ClassFactory(LineTooLongItemRenderer)}" />
 <mx:DataGridColumn ataField="vnic"     headerText="host" />   
  itemRenderer="{new ClassFactory(LineTooLongItemRenderer)}" />

 </mx:columns>
 </mx:DataGrid>
 </mx:Canvas>
 </mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: I have tried to do your example on my PC. It works fine in all cases. Could you say how the LineTooLongItemRenderer looks like? I suppose the problem is there.